# My iOS app defaults to French when debugging despite it being configured for English

Tags: xcode, localization

I'm using Xcode 9.2 (and Swift).

Since adding English and French localization stub files, my App has defaulted to returning French in calls using `DateFormatter` when running thru XCode. When a device, unconnected to Xcode, runs the app, the language of English is correctly used.

In PROJECT/Info/Localizations I have "English - Development Language" and "French" listed.

In my project's `plist`, the key `Localization native development region` is set to `en`.

Xcode runs English, as does my Mac.

I have tried deleting DervicedData, cleaning the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you misconfigured your scheme and selected an application language or region other than the default.

To check this, navigate to **Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme**, select the scheme you are currently using from the top left button and navigate to **Options**. Here, **Application Language** should say **System Language** and **Application Region** should say **System Region** (that is, if you want to test your app with your current system settings).

[image: Application Language and System Language settings inside the scheme options]